# Overloading XOR operator with templated operator fails

Tags: c++

I want to Xor two values, one being a null pointer and one being a pointer to a template class `Node`, and since I will have too do this several times, I do not fancy writing out `reinterpret_cast` for all  of them, so I wrote a function to do it for me. The function works just fine, but for some reason, when I make it an operator, no matter how I call it (I have tried the normal way to call an operator and function style, both give different errors) it throws a compile error. Below is the operator and the function:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<(std::is_pointer<T>::value || std::is_null_pointer<T>::value) && (std::is_pointer<U>::value || std::is_null_pointer<U>::value)>::type>
uintptr_t* operator^(T left, U right)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(left) ^ reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(right));
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<(std::is_pointer<T>::value || std::is_null_pointer<T>::value) && (std::is_pointer<U>::value || std::is_null_pointer<U>::value)>::type>
uintptr_t* XorPtr(T left, U right)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(left) ^ reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(right));
}
```

Again, the function works fine, but the operator throws error. When calling it function style it give the error `"^": no matching overloaded function found` and `Failed to specialize function template 'uintptr_t* operator ^(T,U)'` and the normal operator call says that the operands are invalid.

Here is how I am calling the operators:

```
operator^(nullptr, prev->both);
nullptr ^ prev->both;
```

Where prev->both is a pointer to a template class.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: How do you call `^` operator?

Comment: Are you providing an object reference to one side and a nullptr to the other? Because it looks like your template only accepts pointers.

Comment: Wouldn't `nullptr` be the identity element for XOR, anyway?

Comment: You can't overload an `operator` when both parameters are pointers. One of the parameters must be (a reference to) an object instead. And in the case where you want to pass `nullptr` explicitly, that parameter should preferably be declared as `std::nullptr_t`

Comment: References are not being passed, as I made it so this only works with pointers. @SRhm, there is an example call at the bottom.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is there a reason for this, or is it just something the standard says?

Comment: @KrystianS you can't overload operators for built-in types, and a pointer is a built-in type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining an operator overload, because you fail to meet the definition:

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function that has at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration.

Operations involving types other than these always follow the semantics for built-in types; you can't change the effect of (for example) applying an operator to a pair of pointers, because it already has meaning (at least, if the operator is `-`), or a pointer and an integer, or an integer and a floating-point number.

Comment: @KrystianS: Something you might like is "named operators"... if you have a global instance `ptr` of class type, then you can make `nullptr ^ptr^ prev->both` work.  See [Yakk's famous explanation](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=100233)